# No attribute replace with csv file strings

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I have a csv file of many url's. I am writing a program to extract information from all of these sites.

Right now I open the csv file, read it, and append every link to a list.

```
links = []
with open("x.csv", 'r') as file:
    urls = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for url in urls:
        links.append(url)
```

I then iterate through this list and am trying to use the links as a string and extract information from each link.

```
for link in links:
    url = link
    response = requests.get(url)
```

The problem is I kept getting an error saying:
`requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://link']"` each time I tried to run the code and I figured it was because the string contained brackets (`[ ]`) and quotes (`'`), so I tried to replace these characters and get each string to be just the url information.

```
for link in links:
    link.replace("'", "")
    link.replace("[", "")
    link.replace("]", "")
    url = link
    response = requests.get(url)
```

However when I did that I got an error that said: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Any ideas on what the issue may be or a better way to iterate through a list of url's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `''.join(link)` to return `list` as a `string`.

```
for link in links:
    url =''.join(link)
    response = requests.get(url)
```